# My Sudoku Backtracking Algorithim only works part of the time, can anyone help me improve it?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow, backtracking

I have a recursive algorithm that is supposed to take in a partially or fully empty Sudoku board (represented an int[][] where 0 represents a blank space) and fill it. It works for empty boards and for most other boards I input but occasionally I get a stack overflow error pointing to lines 54 and 40 (at the statements  grid = copyGrid(emptyFill(grid, current + 1, cant)); ) Can anyone help me improve it?

```
  //Creating and filling a board Recursive Methods
//Current represents the index for every cell on the board from 0 to 80 inclusive
//cant holds an array of values that the function may not place for each index 
public static int[][] emptyFill(int[][] grid, int current, int[][] cant){
    if(isFull(grid)){
        return grid; 
    } 
    else if(getCellAt(grid, current) == 0){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i ++){
            if(works(i, current / 9, current % 9, grid) && notInCant(cant, current, i)){
                grid[current / 9][current % 9] = i;
                //Line 40 below this comment
                grid = copyGrid(emptyFill(grid, current + 1, cant));
                return grid; 
            }
        }
        /*Backtracks backwards if no number was found by keeping track of what numbers we have tried. Should clear 
        up the cant list if we backtrack further than it */
        for(int i = current; i < cant.length; i ++){
            clearRow(cant, i);
        }
        addToRow(cant, current - 1,  getCellAt(grid, current - 1)); 
        setCellTo(grid, current, 0); 
        setCellTo(grid, current - 1, 0); 
        //Line 54 below this comment
        grid = copyGrid(emptyFill(grid, current -1, cant));
        return grid; 
    }
    else{
        grid  = copyGrid(emptyFill(grid, current + 1, cant));
        return grid; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are lines 54 and 40 here? Can you write comments pointing to them?

Comment: Your "backtracking" is suspicious: when you clear a cell you should exit the function, otherwise your recursion depth does not correspond to the number of cells you have filled in. This way you risk to recurse indefinitely, without ever filling the whole grid.

Comment: @trincot thank you I understand it better and I was able to fix it

Comment: If you did fix it, I'd suggest writing an answer so this question doesn't remain open

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it, the issue was that when the program wasn't able to fill in a cell, it would "Backtrack" by clearing the current and previous cell updating the list of numbers that couldn't be placed and then calling the program again. This lead to the function being called too many times. The new function instead simply clears the cell and exits the function when it can not find a suitable number. This allows the function to backtrack without calling itself again and actually go back to the previous call. This is the updated function.

```
public boolean emptyFill(int[][] grid, int current){
    if(isFull(grid)){
        return true; 
    } 
    else if(getCellAt(grid, current) == 0){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i ++){
            if(works(i, current / 9, current % 9, grid) && notInCant( current, i)){
                grid[current / 9][current % 9] = i;
                if( emptyFill(grid, current + 1)) return true; 
                grid[current / 9][current % 9] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }
    else{
       return emptyFill(grid, current + 1);
    }

}
```